# Load SIlverlight 4 components in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, silverlight, google-chrome

Is it possible to load silverlight components in Google Chrome if possible can any one tell what are the changes needs to be made in the existing component.

I am using Silverlight 4

Comment: Was Chrome installed on your Dev machine before you installed the SL4 Beta?

Comment: yes Chrome was installed before sl4

Comment: So have you tried it?  What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight 4 will be supported in Google Chrome.

Comment: No changes - it will be a fully supported browser for SL4.